# Precedence Order in C/C++

Tags: c, operator-precedence

I wish to know that why this code shows different Output on different compilers.
Here's the Code:-

```
int a = 5;
printf("%d %d",a++,++a);
```

Output:- 6 7 (Visual Studio)

Output:- 6 6 (CodeBlocks)

Comment: This is undefined behavior. Look up "sequence point" to understand why.

Comment: This has nothing to do with precedence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is undefined behavior and it depends on the compiler which you are using. And to add it has nothing to do with the order of precedence.

You may check [Precedence and Order of Evaluation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx)

Also from C99 standard:

> The order of evaluation of the operands is unspecified. If an attempt
>   is made to modify the result of an assignment operator or to access it
>   after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.